# input/output error when copy or link a file containing escape characters from home directory to a nfs system

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs, symbolic-link

Suppose that I have a home directory `/home/mydir`(not have sudo permission),which have some file contain time format (YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS) in filename, when I try to copy or link these files to a nfs directory, it will report an error,something like

```
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/NARR_3D:2013-01-03_00': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/NARR_3D:2013-01-03_03': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/NARR_3D:2013-01-03_06': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/met_em.d01.2013-01-02_06:00:00.nc': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/met_em.d01.2013-01-02_09:00:00.nc': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/met_em.d01.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/met_em.d01.2013-01-02_15:00:00.nc': Input/output error
```

or

```
$ cp ~/tests/2013010206/met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12\:00\:00.nc .
cp: cannot stat './met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc': Input/output error
```

I think that it is related with the escape characters backslash `\` in the time format (`12\:00\:00`)or say the `\:` for all file, since when I use this command

```
$ cp ~/tests/2013010206/met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12\:00\:00.nc met_em_2013-01-02_12
$ ls
met_em_2013-01-02_12
```

It is ok. So the problem is how to deal with it, it there some setting in the NFS can modify, because this kind of time format file is needed for a lot of my running exe.

And the following is the setting in `/etc/fstab`

```
IP:/share1   /share1     nfs     rw,sync,nosuid,rsize=65536,wsize=65536    0 0
```

Comment: Can you try the following command on the NFS file system: `touch A:B ; ls`

Comment: `$ touch A:B; ls   
                                                                                                                    
touch: cannot touch 'A:B': Input/output error
`

Comment: Certainly my answer below applies to you. Your NFS server is probably a Windows machine with NTFS disk system. Can you check this?

Comment: ok,thanks.  I will aks the administrator about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit***: @AllenZhang : I completely misunderstood your question by reading all *nfs*'s in your question text as *NTFS*. However, the problem may still be related to NTFS in case that your *nfs server* is a Windows machine.

---

Some characters (including `" * / : < > ? \ |`) are not allowed in file names in an NTFS partition. See [Wikipedia Filename topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename). Your problem is related to `:` (the colon) character. You have to replace it with another character while copying.

---

As a demo, look at the following commands ran on an *NTFS* volume:

```
$ touch met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc 
touch: setting times of 'met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc': No such file or directory
$ ls met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc 
ls: cannot access 'met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc': No such file or directory
$ df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      312568640 264057464  48511176  85% /media/my_user/WD_300GB
$ blkid /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="WD_300GB" UUID="2E584CDC584CA505" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0015bef7-01"
$ sudo file -sL /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 63, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 625137281, $MFT start cluster 786432, $MFTMirror start cluster 39071080, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number 02e584cdc584ca505; containsMicrosoft Windows XP/VISTA bootloader NTLDR
```

Compare it with commands ran on an *ext4* volume:

```
$ cd
$ touch met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc
$ ls  met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc
met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc
$ df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda       479670976 130386736 324848528  29% /home
$ blkid /dev/sda
/dev/sda: LABEL="home filesystem" UUID="91ee80e9-39bc-4521-bd48-46136744435b" TYPE="ext4"
$ sudo file -sL /dev/sda
/dev/sda: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=91ee80e9-39bc-4521-bd48-46136744435b, volume name "home filesystem" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)
```

Going back to our *NTFS* volume:

```
$ touch $(echo met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc | tr ':' '-')
$ ls
met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12-00-00.nc
```

---

So, if you want to copy some files from a directory to your *NTFS* (or *nfs*) volume, you can use this script, which will replace all colons (`:`) with underscore (`_`) characters, **while copying**:

```
#!/bin/bash
destination=./your_nfs_directory
for fn in "$@" ; do
  newfn=$(basename "$fn")
  cp -iv "$fn" "${destination}/${newfn//:/_}"
done
```

Don't forget to replace your *real* destination *nfs* directory in the line starting with `destination=`. The script may be used like the following example:

```
./script_name ./2013*/*2013-01*
```

If your file names contain other non-allowed characters, you have to update it to take care of them also.

---

**Note:** I remounted the *NTFS* volume by hand. I suppose this skips some special mount options for Windows compatibility. This time I *was* able to create a file with a `:` in it:

```
$ cd
$ sudo umount /dev/sdc1
$ mkdir /tmp/mountpoint
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /tmp/mountpoint
$ cd /tmp/mountpoint
$ touch met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc 
$ ls
met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc
```

Comment: Do you mean that there is no options for `nfs` to allow filenames containing `:` . Because for my case, it will produce a lot of input or output containing `:` in the filename when `mpirun`.

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. I have no experience about `mpirun`, but can you not configure it so that it will not use these special characters in the file names it create?

Comment: These file names containing `:` (or say time) are the standard format of some `exe` needed. Maybe I need to modify the code, which is a large system.

Comment: I suppose you can remount the _ntfs_ volume with other options as explained in https://superuser.com/questions/515533/how-to-create-drive-symlink-with-colon-for-ntfs-3g-symlinks-in-ntfs-3g-folder

Comment: @AllenZhang I completely misunderstood your question by reading all `nfs`s as `ntfs`. However, the problem may still be related to NTFS in case that your "nfs server" is a Windows machine. Can you check this?

Comment: Yes,the `nfs` shared directory is based on `windows` machine.

Comment: Then, you will have to copy the files using a new name, where the colon is replaced with another character, as the sample command with `tr` that I have given in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I can rename these filenames temporary, but the 'exe` which is compiled from a large system still need the input of containing `:`, so maybe I should modify the code further so that I can run it in this `windows` type `nfs` shared directory.

Comment: By the way, if I want to copy a lot files, how should I use the sample command? Could I remain the filename in the source directory, but use the command to copy files and rename it at the same time?

Comment: Yes you can. Use the cp command in a for loop, for example as explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102647/how-to-rename-multiple-files-in-single-command-or-script-in-unix As a "thank you" you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of my answer.

Comment: It seems that we need to rename the file in the original directory and then copy these to destination directory, but we need to rename back in the original dir. Is it possible directly using the `tr` and `cp` to copy files and rename it at the same time while we don't need rename in source directory?

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample script. Please note that, any discussions about the script is out of the scope of this Question! :)